# Problem on sending a POST Request by WebClient, passing a complex JSON body

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-webflux, webclient

I hope someone can help me.

I prepared on postman.co site a POST Request with a JSON body like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "account": {
            "accountId": "1234",
            "mail": "j.doe@mail.com"
        },
        "address": null
    },
    "registrationDate": "2021-07-01",
    "text": null,
    "description": "something",
    "amount": 800,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "tex1": null,
    "text2": null
    "anotherObject": {
        "id": null,
        "isNew": false,
        "number": "12345",
        "type": "STUDENT",
        "student": {
            "fiscalCode": "XLFGBT34G34V432W",
            "tex1": null,
            "text2": null
        },
        "teacher": null
    }
```

}

On postman went all pretty quite, with a correct response. So I replicated it on my java code, How you can see below:

```
AccountDTO account = new AccountDTO("1234", "j.doe@mail.com");
UserDTO user = new UserDTO("John Doe", account, null);
StudentDTO student = new StudentDTO("XLFGBT34G34V432W", null, null);
AnotherObjectDTO anotherObject = new AnotherObjectDTO(null, false, "12345", "STUDENT", student, null);
RequestDTO request = new RequestDTO(user, "2021-07-01", null,
            "something", 800, "EUR", null, null, anotherObject);
```

Finally, I used the following code to do my POST Request:

```
public String postUserInformationById(String accountId, RequestDTO request) {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri(POST_ACCOUNT_INFORMATION, accountId)
            .header("Auth-Schema", AUTH_SCHEMA)
            .header("apikey", API_KEY)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
                System.out.println("4xx error");
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("4xx"));
              })
              .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> {
                System.out.println("5xx error");
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("5xx"));
              })
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
}
```

But I receive a "Response 400 BAD_REQUEST".

```
Encoding [RequestDTO(user=UserDTO(name=John Doe, account=AccountDTO(accountId=1234 (truncated)...]
```

Does someone have any suggestions, how can I check if I'm sending the right request?

Update:
Here the error log as requested by GnanaJeyam

```
17:44:38.670 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG 
reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector - [id:0ca8d08a] Connecting to [sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443].
17:44:38.712 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] Registering pool release on close event for channel
17:44:38.713 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] Channel connected, now: 1 active connections, 0 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
17:44:38.963 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler - [id: 0x0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] HANDSHAKEN: protocol:TLSv1.2 cipher suite:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
17:44:38.964 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443]}, [connected])
17:44:38.973 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a-1, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] onStateChange(GET{uri=/, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443]}}, [configured])
17:44:38.975 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect - [id:0ca8d08a-1, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] Handler is being applied: {uri=https://sandbox.io/api/v1.0/users/12345/informations, method=POST}
17:44:38.977 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a-1, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1.0/users/12345/informations, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443]}}, [request_prepared])
17:44:39.037 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder - [4e4efc1b] Encoding [RequestDTO(user=UserDTO(name=John Doe, account=AccountDTO(accountId=1234 (truncated)...]
17:44:39.063 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a-1, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1.0/users/12345/informations, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443]}}, [request_sent])
17:44:40.180 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Brotli - brotli4j not in the classpath; Brotli support will be unavailable.
17:44:40.182 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations - [id:0ca8d08a-1, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] Received response (auto-read:false) : [Date=Fri, 16 Jul 2021 15:44:40 GMT, Server=Apache, Max-Forwards=19, Via=1.0 fbkprsndgtm01 (), 1.0 fbkprsndgtm01 (), X-CorrelationID=Id-67a9f16022bf0ba985c735d6 0; Id-67a9f160b8be591733191a42 0, Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000, Content-Type=application/json, Vary=User-Agent, Connection=close, Transfer-Encoding=chunked]
17:44:40.182 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a-1, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1.0/users/12345/informations, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443]}}, [response_received])
17:44:40.186 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions - [4e4efc1b] [0ca8d08a-1, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
4xx error
17:44:40.204 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive - [id:0ca8d08a-1, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
17:44:40.208 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations - [id:0ca8d08a-1, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] Received last HTTP packet
17:44:40.211 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1.0/users/12345/informations, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443]}}, [response_completed])
17:44:40.213 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1.0/users/12345/informations, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443]}}, [disconnecting])
17:44:40.219 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 ! R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] Channel closed, now: 0 active connections, 0 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
17:44:40.220 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id:0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 ! R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x0ca8d08a, L:/192.168.1.11:63844 ! R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443]}, [disconnecting])
```

Comment: Could you update the error log with little more information.

Comment: The java code supplied does not show the objects and parameter names, could be a misspelled parameter. We need full logs, a 400 tells us you have done something wrong but you have not provided us the full code so its impossible to tell. Voted to close, lack of debugging details.

Comment: I just added the debug details

Comment: does this downstream service return a body on a 400 response? This will often give you an indication of why the request is bad. Have you tried printing out the response body?

Comment: Please Michael, can you give me more information about how I should do it?

Comment: in the `onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response` you have a response. that responce object should have a function to extract the body and then you print that body

Comment: `{
  "status" : "KO",
  "errors" :  [
  {
   "code" : "API000",
   "description" : "TipoSpese p (truncated)...`

Comment: thank you all of you. But can I return this Response JSON object in a java class? I would like substitute the '.bodyToMono(String.class)' with a Object.class which contains 'status', 'errors' and 'payload'.

Comment: yes you can map the response body to a custom java object instead of a `String`. By default for a json body, spring boot will use `jackson` to do the unmarshalling.